# Black images or memory issue with Hugging Face StableDiffusion pipleline, M1 Pro, PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, apple-m1, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

So I'm making a project for a school that offers image generation using stable diffusion. It was working perfectly fine until I upgraded the Pytorch version for "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-x4-upscaler" model. Since then all the other images generated are black because they get flagged NSFW.

The code hasn't changed but I have updated Mac OS to 13.3.1 recently and I tested many different versions of PyTorch, Diffusers, and Transformers, but I can't get it to work as it did before. Since the code didn't change the problem has to do with the package version.

With the latest PyTorch 2.0 I am able to generate working images but I cannot use `torch_dtype=torch.float16` in the pipeline since it's not supported and I seem to be getting the following insufficient memory issues now.

`RuntimeError: MPS backend out of memory (MPS allocated: 18.04 GB, other allocations: 94.99 MB, max allowed: 18.13 GB). Tried to allocate 4.00 KB on private pool. Use PYTORCH_MPS_HIGH_WATERMARK_RATIO=0.0 to disable upper limit for memory allocations (may cause system failure). INFO:     Stopping reloader process [15702]`

These are the following models and piplines I used.

```py
main_model_id = "runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5"
inpainting_model_id = "runwayml/stable-diffusion-inpainting"
upscaler_model_id = "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-x4-upscaler"

text2imgPipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(main_model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16).to(
    device)
text2imgPipe.enable_attention_slicing()

img2imgPipe = StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline.from_pretrained(main_model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16).to(
    device)
img2imgPipe.enable_attention_slicing()

inpaintingPipe = StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline.from_pretrained(inpainting_model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16).to(
    device)
inpaintingPipe.enable_attention_slicing()

upscalerPipe = StableDiffusionUpscalePipeline.from_pretrained(upscaler_model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16).to(
    device)
upscalerPipe.enable_attention_slicing()
```

These are the current package version I have.

```bash
transformers              4.26.0
torchaudio                2.0.0
torchvision               0.14.1
pytorch                   2.0.0
diffusers                 0.12.0
huggingface-hub           0.13.4
python                    3.10.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `torch.float32` (uses more memory than torch.float16) or [`fp16fixes.fp16_fixes()`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/105839), and add `mps.empty_cache()` before your `from_pretrained()` lines. That should work on a 8GB M1 Mac Mini. Alternatively, try PyTorch 2.3.0.dev20240103+.